# Provide access to a folder in Azure Blob container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am able to restrict access to a blob container or to particular file using SAS token, But I'm not able to generate SAS token at folder level in Azure Blob Storage.

Is there a way to provide access to only a particular folder in a Azure Blob Storage. (We have many folders in a blob container, we need to provide Read access  to a single folder to client)

Comment: because you can an unlimited number of container, you could flatten your structure folder with a naming convention (i.e. container name = folder1-folder2-folder3)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a way to provide access to only a particular folder in a
>   Azure Blob Storage.

As of today, No. As you mentioned, SAS token can be used to restrict access to either an entire blob container or an individual blob. This is because a folder in blob storage is virtual and not a real folder.

Comment: Just want to know if things changed in couple years ?? Can we limit a user to be able to /upload/create to ONE specific container in a SA using RBAC or SAS ?? Or do I need to just create a separate SA for which will have just That single container ??

Comment: Nope, still the same :) as the folders in blob storage are virtual.

Comment: Yea i get it about the folders..but I am trying limit access to a Container !

Comment: Are the things changed in 2024?
Same Storage Account with Blob storage (cold tier) - and multiple shares with different access permissions for each of them (other than SAS Token)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if one can do that in Storage Gen1, but in Gen2, open storage explorer->your_container->your_folder. You will see this. [image]

1. Click on Manage Access.
2. On the right side, a pane like this will open up. [image]
3. Add your user. It will be added after the Mask.
4. Select the user, tick the access and pick one or more of Read, Write and Execute.